# Compare string with GM_GetValue not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to compare value of TestScript with string "Investisseur" But this seems not working and I don't go into the if statement.

```
console.log(GM_getValue(TestScript));

    if(GM_getValue(TestScript) == "Investisseur")
{
//Should be there
}
```

`console.log(GM_getValue(TestScript));`  returns :
[image]

So the if condition would return true and not false .. What Am I doing Wrong ?

**EDIT**

It seems like the check before reset my @GM_getValue:

```
 if(GM_getValue(TestScript) == "Investisseur" || GM_getValue(TestScript) == null || GM_getValue(TestScript) == undefined ){

        GM_setValue(TimeoutMain, 1000)
    }else if(GM_getValue(TestScript) == "Emetteur"){
        GM_setValue(TimeoutMain, 10000)
    }
```

Any Idea why ? When I try to `Console.log` after this it display nothing .. Why is the value deleted ?

Maybe more understandable with a screen there  :
[image]

Comment: GM_getValue(TestScript) is not returning a string; it's probably returning an Object. Change your last line to 

console.log( JSON.stringify( GM_getValue( TestScript ) );

This should help you figure out what's going on. If not, we'll need more code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`TestScript` might have extra spaces.
`trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Try replacing:

```
GM_getValue(TestScript)
```

with:

```
if (GM_getValue(TestScript).trim() == "Investisseur")
```

Comment: console.log(typeof GM_getValue(TestScript)) to see if GM_getValue(TestScript)) is a string

Comment: if GM_getValue(TestScript)) does not  return a string comparing it with "Investisseur"  always be falsy